# Get selected checkboxes and add to total

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have three sets of checkboxes (serviceA, B & C) with 5 checkboxes each, each set having the same class name.

I need to count the checked checkboxes of each set, multiply them with a,b,c (different value for each service A,B,C) and display the sum of all selections in a textbox, div or whatever.

So far I'm getting the desired result and it all works ok but I'd like the jquery experts to tell me if there's a better way or maybe a shorter or even tidier way to write the code.

Here's my code, also at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fQTUp/66/):

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
serviceA1 <input type="checkbox" name="serviceA1" id="serviceA1" value="1" class="serviceA" /><br />
serviceA2 <input type="checkbox" name="serviceA2" id="serviceA2" value="1" class="serviceA" /><br />
serviceA3 <input type="checkbox" name="serviceA3" id="serviceA3" value="1" class="serviceA" /><br />
serviceA4 <input type="checkbox" name="serviceA4" id="serviceA4" value="1" class="serviceA" /><br />

serviceB1 <input type="checkbox" name="serviceB1" id="serviceB1" value="1" class="serviceB" /><br />
serviceB2 <input type="checkbox" name="serviceB2" id="serviceB2" value="1" class="serviceB" /><br />
serviceB3 <input type="checkbox" name="serviceB3" id="serviceB3" value="1" class="serviceB" /><br />
serviceB4 <input type="checkbox" name="serviceB4" id="serviceB4" value="1" class="serviceB" /><br />

<p>Total<input type="text" name="TotlCost" id="TotalCost" size="10"/></p>
</body>
</html>​
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input:checkbox").click(function(event) {
        var total = 0;
        var a = 5;
        var b = 10;
        var c = 8;
        var totalA = 0;
        var totalB = 0;
        var totalC = 0;

        $(".serviceA:checkbox:checked").each(function() {
            totalA += parseInt($(this).val());
        });
        $(".serviceB:checkbox:checked").each(function() {
            totalB += parseInt($(this).val());
        });
        $(".serviceC:checkbox:checked").each(function() {
            totalC += parseInt($(this).val());
        });

        total = totalA*a + totalB*b + totalC*c;

        if (total == 0) {
            $('#TotalCost').val('0');
        } else {
            $('#TotalCost').val(total);
        }
    });
});​
```

UPDATE: Also, #TotalCost already has a value from other selections on the page, how do I add the checkboxes total to #TotalCost?

NEW ADDITION: After applying the accepted answer to my code, I now have another question. One of the controls on my form is a select:

```
<select id="symb" class="big" name="symb">
  <option value="1#10#6">Basic Personal</option>
  <option value="2#20#6">Basic Family</option>
  <option value="10#90#12">Advanced Personal</option>
  <option value="11#120#12">Advanced Family</option>
</select>
```

with the middle number in the delimeted value is the cost of each selection. How can I add that cost to the #cost field each time the user makes a selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have rewritten your example so that it adds/subtracts from the value in `#TotalCost`.  This means that checking/unchecking the checkboxes should update the value in `#TotalCost` correctly, even if the value in `#TotalCost` has been set from somewhere else.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input.serviceA:checkbox").click(function(event) {
        var total = parseInt($("#TotalCost").val());

        if (isNaN(total)) total = 0;

        if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
            total += 5;
        } else {
            total -= 5;
        }

        $("#TotalCost").val(total);
    });

    $("input.serviceB:checkbox").click(function(event) {
        var total = parseInt($("#TotalCost").val());

        if (isNaN(total)) total = 0;

        if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
            total += 10;
        } else {
            total -= 10;
        }

        $("#TotalCost").val(total);
    });

    $("input.serviceC:checkbox").click(function(event) {
        var total = parseInt($("#TotalCost").val());

        if (isNaN(total)) total = 0;

        if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
            total += 8;
        } else {
            total -= 8;
        }

        $("#TotalCost").val(total);
    });

});​
```

The above can almost certainly be improved.  For example, if all the checkboxes where given the same class, e.g. `service` and the `value` parameter was updated to have the value to be added/subtracted:

```
<html>
<body>
serviceA1 <input type="checkbox" name="serviceA1" id="serviceA1" value="5" class="service" /><br />
serviceA2 <input type="checkbox" name="serviceA2" id="serviceA2" value="5" class="service" /><br />
serviceA3 <input type="checkbox" name="serviceA3" id="serviceA3" value="5" class="service" /><br />
serviceA4 <input type="checkbox" name="serviceA4" id="serviceA4" value="5" class="service" /><br />

serviceB1 <input type="checkbox" name="serviceB1" id="serviceB1" value="10" class="service" /><br />
serviceB2 <input type="checkbox" name="serviceB2" id="serviceB2" value="10" class="service" /><br />
serviceB3 <input type="checkbox" name="serviceB3" id="serviceB3" value="10" class="service" /><br />
serviceB4 <input type="checkbox" name="serviceB4" id="serviceB4" value="10" class="service" /><br />

<p>Total<input type="text" name="TotlCost" id="TotalCost" size="10"/></p>
</body>
</html>​
```

You could simplify the code to the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input.service:checkbox").click(function(event) {
        var total = parseInt($("#TotalCost").val());

        var value = parseInt($(this).val());

        if (isNaN(total)) total = 0;

        if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
            total += value;
        } else {
            total -= value;
        }

        $("#TotalCost").val(total);
    });
});​
```

Comment: Spot on! Thanks, I really liked the simple thought "if all the checkboxes where given the same class, e.g. service and the value parameter was updated to have the value to be added/subtracted"

Comment: Please have a look at my latest update, I've added a new question at the end. Thanks!

Comment: @bikey77 I think you should probably ask that in a new question, you can link back to this Q&A. You are turning this into a conversation which is not how StackOverflow is supposed to work.

Answer (score 2):

you also try

```
$('input.className:checked').length;
```

for count total checked checkBox in particuler checkbox class

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$('[name=serviceA]:checked').length;
$('[name=serviceB]:checked').length;
$('[name=serviceC]:checked').length;
```

if you want alle checked together

```
$('checkbox:checked').length;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input:checkbox").click(function(event) {
        var total = 0;
        var a = 5;
        var b = 10;
        var c = 8;
        var totalA = 0;

        $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
           totalA = parseInt($(this).val());
            if($(this).hasClass('serviceA')){
               total +=totalA*a;   
            }
            if($(this).hasClass('serviceB')){
               total += totalA*b;   
            }
            if($(this).hasClass('serviceC')){
               total +=totalA*c;   
            }

        });
      if (total == 0) {
            $('#TotalCost').val('0');
        } else {
            $('#TotalCost').val(total);
        }

});
});​
```

Here the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N37en/)

Or you can use this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input:checkbox").click(function() {
        var total = 0;
        var a = 5;
        var b = 10;
        var c = 8;
        var lengthA = $(".serviceA:checkbox:checked").length;
        var lengthB = $(".serviceB:checkbox:checked").length;
        var lengthC = $(".serviceC:checkbox:checked").length;
        total += lengthA*a + lengthB *b + lengthC *c;   
        $('#TotalCost').val(total);

});
});​
```

Here is [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VwfrA/2/)

Comment: @bikey : You can add total to totalcost value. Use totalcost + parseInt(total)