# Split option value and add to field

Tags: jquery, select, split

I have

```
<select id="symb" class="big" name="symb">
  <option value="1#10#6">Basic Personal</option>
  <option value="2#20#6">Basic Family</option>
  <option value="10#90#12">Advanced Personal</option>
  <option value="11#120#12">Advanced Family</option>
</select>
```

and I need to split the selected value and add the middle number to field #cost.

There are other controls on the same form that add their value #cost so I have to take under consideration that I need to keep the initial value and add the option value on the onblur/onchange event for #symb.

You can also check my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113875/get-selected-checkboxes-and-add-to-total) so you get the bigger picture.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#symb").change(function(){
   $("#cost ").val($("option:selected", this).val().split("#")[1])
});
```

Comment: he want to add the value to `#cost` not to overwrite it

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#symb").change(function(){
        $("#cost").val(parseInt($("option:selected").val().split('#')[1])+parseInt(document.getElementById("cost").defaultValue))
    });
```

Comment: Do i put this in the onready function or in a user defined function and call it when a change is made to each form control?

Comment: Ok, it works but not entirely correct. Thing is, it adds the value of #symb to #cost but if I select an #symb option with lower value, it keeps adding to #cost, instead of subtracting.

Comment: mean you want subtraction when #cost is greater that #symb value

Comment: Lets say that #cost is initially 20 and I select #symb->90 so #cost should now be 90+20=110. Then, I go back and select #symb->20, #cost should then be 20+20=40.

Comment: Finally found the solution based on your help. Check my answer above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With Somebody is in trouble's help and a bit of luck on my own, i found the solution to what I was looking for. I'm posting it here for future reference.

```
var initial; 
    $("#symb").focus(function () {
        initial = parseInt($("#cost").val()); // assign the initial value before change
    }).change(function() {
        var symb =  parseInt($("option:selected").val().split('#')[1]);
        $("#cost").val(parseInt(initial+(symb-initial))); 
    });
```